# Array.ToString() returning System.Char[] c#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, output

Im making a hangman game, at the start of the game the word that the player must guess is printed as stars. I have just started making it again after attempting to write it once and just having messy code that i couldn't bug fix. So I decided it best to write it again. The only problem is, when i try to get my array to print out by using array.ToString(); it just returns System.char[]. See below.

code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string PlayerOneWord;
        string PlayerTwoGuess;
        int lives = 5;

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to hangman!\n PLayer one, Please enter the word which player Two needs to guess!");
        PlayerOneWord = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        var stars = new char[PlayerOneWord.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < stars.Length ; i++)
        {
                stars[i] = '*';
        }

        string StarString = stars.ToString();

        Console.Write("Word to Guess: {0}" , StarString);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

output:

[image: Output]

The output should say `Word to guess: Hello`.

Please will someone explain why this is happening as its not the first time I have run into this problem.

Comment: `new String(charArray)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `ToString` on a simple array only returns `"T[]"` regardless what the type `T` is. It doesn't have any special handling for `char[]`.

To convert a `char[]` to `string` you can use:

```
string s = new string(charArray);
```

But for your concrete problem there is an even simpler solution:

```
string stars = new string('*', PlayerOneWord.Length);
```

The constructor [`public String(char c, int count)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) repeats `c` `count` times.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `stars` is an array of chars. This is the reason you get this error. As it is stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns a string that represents the current object.

In order you get a string from the characters in this array, you could use this:

```
 Console.Write("Word to Guess: {0}" , new String(stars));
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be:

```
string StarString = new string(stars);
```

ToString() calls the standard implementation of the Array-class's ToString-method which is the same for all Arrays and similarily to object only returns the fully qualified class name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
static string ConvertCharArr2Str(char[] chs)
{
    var s = "";
    foreach (var c in chs)
    {
        s += c;
    }
    return s;
}
```